# How to pass a parameter to Collection parse? backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How could one pass a parameter through the parse/fetch function?
I want to pass the variable **VARIABLE_PARAMETER** in the lower Initialize-part.

Otherwise I have to write three mostly identical Collections.

Thank you for you help.

**app.js**

```
//--------------
// Collections
//--------------

    DiagnoseApp.Collections.Param1_itemS = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: DiagnoseApp.Models.Param1_item,
        url: 'TestInterface.xml',
        parse: function (data) { 
            var parsed = [];

            $(data).find(/*VARIABLE_PARAMETER*/).find('PARAMETER').each(function (index) {
                var v_number = $(this).attr('Number');
                var v_Desc_D = $(this).attr('Desc_D');
                parsed.push({ data_type: v_data_type, number: v_number, Desc_D: v_Desc_D});
            });

            return parsed;
        },

        fetch: function (options) { 
            options = options || {};
            options.dataType = "xml";
            return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
        }
    });
```

This is the way I initialize the app:

```
    //--------------
    // Initialize
    //--------------

    var VARIABLE_PARAMETER = "OFFLINE";

    var offline_Collection = new DiagnoseApp.Collections.Param1_itemS();
    var offline_Collection_View = new DiagnoseApp.Views.Param1_itemS({collection: offline_Collection});


    //VARIABLE_PARAMETER has to be passed here in fetch I guess ??

     offline_Collection.fetch({
        success: function() {
              console.log("JSON file load was successful", offline_Collection);

              offline_Collection_View.render();
          },
        error: function(){
           console.log('There was some error in loading and processing the JSON file');
        }

    });
```

Comment: Why not have a separate node in your `XML` which is your variable parameter when you send the response back from the BE ?

Comment: The `XML-file` is fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fetch` method accepts an `option` argument : http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch
The `parse` method also accepts an `option` argument: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse 
These objects are actually the same. So you may write:

```
parse: function (data, options) { 
        var parsed = [];

        $(data).find(options.variableParameter).find('PARAMETER').each(function (index) {
            var v_number = $(this).attr('Number');
            var v_Desc_D = $(this).attr('Desc_D');
            parsed.push({ data_type: v_data_type, number: v_number, Desc_D: v_Desc_D});
        });

        return parsed;
    },
```

Comment: So is it possible to call it like this: `offlineCollection.fetch({ success: {..},error:{..}}, VARIABLE_PARAMETER) ;`?

Comment: No, the `fetch` method accepts only one argument: `offlineCollection.fetch({ success: {..},error:{..}, variable_parameter: VARIABLE_PARAMETER})`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, but if you want to "pass a parameter" from `fetch` to `parse`, and if that parameter value doesn't change for a given collection, you could just store it in the collection. You could pass the parameter to `fetch` as an additional property in `options`:

```
fetch: function (options) { 
    options = options || {};
    options.dataType = "xml";
    this.variableParameter = options.variableParameter;
    return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
},
```

And then simply retrieve it

```
parse: function (data) { 
    // do something useful with this.variableParameter
    // ...
}
```